Attempting to include a transaction into a certain range of blocks
I'm curious how difficult it would be to ensure that my transaction got included into a specific block. More specifically, if the current most up to date block is block X, how certain can I be that my transaction gets included in a block up to block X+5? What about up to block X+10? What about up to block X+20?
I'm assuming that I would be willing to use pay amount of gas required to bribe block proposers to include my transaction. I think the thing that would make ensuring a transaction got included within the next 5 or 10 blocks most difficult is if the network is congested because of high levels of activity on the Ethereum network, but I'm not sure if anything else would also contribut or the likelihood of getting it done in these cases.

This kind of stuff is probably easiest to do on a private endpoint that accepts bribes. I'm not sure which services offer these nowadays, but at least Flashbots used to have these.
The main idea is that you bypass the typical transaction queue. You submit your transaction to block producers directly, with a bribe, and they include the tx in their blocks, according to certain rules.
Another alternative would be to make the transaction revert if it's not in the right block and just try to get it to succeed with good gas pricing.

Out of the two ways that you’ve mentioned, which one would be more cost efficient considering the bribe cost in the first one and the gas costs for reverting and keep submitting the transaction again (till it gets included in the desired block)?

Using bribes, for sure. But that approach has different characteristics and one should first understand the risks and possibilities associated with that.

This functionality has been called preconfirmed transactions and there are purposes how to implement it, in an MEV context or L2s. For reference, see 1, 2, 3 and there are others...
As far as I know, there are no in production versions implemented, but I may be outdated.
